# Resolving circular dependency when using a class enum

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

The title probably isn't very clear, what I'm talking about is:

Say you have a class A depending on B and a class B depending on A. 
This causes a circular dependency, but can be solved pretty easily:

```cpp
/// a.h
#ifndef __A_H
#define __A_H

struct B;

#include "b.h"

struct A
{
    B *bptr;
    
    A();

    void doStuffWithB();
};

#endif
/// b.h
#ifndef __B_H
#define __B_H

struct A;

#include "a.h"

struct B
{
    A *aptr;
    
    B();

    void doStuffWithA();
};

#endif
```

Boom! Circular dependency resolved.
However, what if I now wanted to use an enum declared in B as an argument in A ?

```
/// a.h ...
struct A
{
    B *bptr;

    A();

    void doStuffWithB(B::Type type); // <-- Compiler smells something funny here
};

/// b.h ...
struct B
{
    enum Type
    {
        // Whatever...
    }
    
    B();
    
    void doStuffWithA();
};
```

Obviously it will not work because the enum isn't yet declared. 
The solution for this would be to just put the enum in it's own header file, but it's really nice to have it attached to the class, so would there be any funny way to do something like that ? I searched around but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: since you use `enum`, as opposed to `enum class`: If the reason to put the enum in the class is so that the members do not pollute the global namespace, then there's an easier solution: Make the enum separate, and use `enum class`.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__A_H`, `__B_H`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: The circular dependency has not been resolved. `a.h` still has `#include “b.h”` and `b.h` still has `#include “a.h”`. Sooner or later that will bite you.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct B;

#include "b.h"
```

In the original version of the two header files this `#include` is completely unnecessary. You'll be happy to learn that the `struct B;` forward declaration is completely sufficient for declaring the `B *` class member. The analogous thing applies for the `struct A;` and the `#include` in the other header file: the `#include` is unnecessary.

And once you made this fortunate discovery, the solution in this specific case becomes obvious: simply put back the `#include "b.h"` back wher eit was.

Only `a.h` needs to `#include` the other file, and fully declare the `B` object in order to make use of its inner `enum`. The reason for the original compilation error is the unneeded include from `b.h` to `a.h`.

When compiling the `b.h`, its `#include` of `a.h` happens before the class and its inner `enum` gets declared. Then, the `#include` from `a.h` to `b.h` does nothing, because it gets blocked by the include guards. And then the `A` class gets compiled without the `B` class, and its inner enum, getting declared.

So, this specific case can be solved, because the dependency on an inner class member is from one of the classes only. What is, actually, an insolvable problem is when two classes have a mutually dependency on each other's inner class member. The only solution is a refactoring, pulling out the inner class type/enums into the global scope, and perhaps using a `using` or a `typedef` to alias an inner class to it.

Comment: At least, this solved my specific case, thank you!